Tackling the 2-D Continuity Equation with a dependent source term
I am modeling what is effectively a conducting plate in (spatial variables $x,y$) which the charge density $\rho$ satisfies the continuity equation with current density $\mathbf{J}$. Because I am assuming steady state in the frequency domain, I can write this as:
$$
j\omega \rho + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0.
$$
In this equation, both $\rho$ and $\mathbf{J}$ are unknown. I can also find the voltage through the relationship $\mathbf{J} = -\sigma \nabla V$. Assuming the conductance is constant, I can rewrite the equation as
$$\nabla^2 V = \frac{j \omega}{\sigma}\rho,$$
which looks like a Poisson equation but both $V$ and $\rho$ are dependent variables here. I have boundary conditions on the charge input and voltage at the edges of the plate, but don't need to get into specifics. Let's just say the plate has a known current source and sink, but the distribution within is unknown.
My issue is that this equation has two dependent variables $\rho$ and $V$ (or $\rho$ and $\mathbf{J}$) and two independent variables, and I have no clue where to start with such problems. It is not underdetermined with a known current source, as is intuitive from the physics of the problem. I have computed the solution numerically using the finite element method, but I want an analytic approach. Does anyone have any resources on such two-dependent-variable equations?

Unless you have another equation, this is underdetermined.

@kieransquared I have a boundary condition at one edge on the charge distribution as a function of space rho(x,0) = rho0(x), and BCs on the other sides. with FEM this is all I need to solve the problem (you can imagine the iterative solution method)
